# Context API Unit test failing with TypeError

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a HOC component `WithContext` (in a file conveniently named `withContext.js`) as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import { DEFAULT_STATE } from './store';
const MyContext = React.createContext(DEFAULT_STATE);


export function WithContext(Component) {
    return function WrapperComponent(props) {
        return (
            <MyContext.Consumer>
                {state => <Component {...props} context={state} />}
            </MyContext.Consumer>
        );
    };
};
```

and a component that uses it as follows

```
import React from "react";
import { WithContext } from './withContext';

const MyComp = (context) => { 
    return (
        <div className="flex dir-col" id="MyComp">
            <p>This is a test</p>
        </div>
    )
};

export default WithContext(MyComp);
```

I also have a unit test that aims to test this `MyComp` component. The unit test follows

```
import React from "react";
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { WithContext } from './withContext';

// We need to configure our DOM 
import jsdom from 'jsdom'
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;
const {document} = (new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>')).window;
global.document = document;
global.window = document.defaultView

Enzyme.configure({
    adapter : new Adapter()
})

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
})

//Takes the context data we want to test, or uses defaults
const getMyContext = (context = {
        state : {}
    }) => {

  // Will then mock the MyContext module being used in our MyComp component
  jest.doMock('withContext', () => {
    return {
      MyContext: {
        Consumer: (props) => props.children(context)
      }
    }
  });

  // We will need to re-require after calling jest.doMock.
  // return the updated MyComp module that now includes the mocked context
  return require('./MyComp').default;

};

describe("MyComp component loading check", () => {
    test("Renders the MyComp component correctly", () => {
        const MyCompContext = getMyContext();
        const wrapper = shallow(<MyComp/>);
        // make sure that we are able to find the header component
        expect(wrapper.find(".flex").hostNodes().length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

However this test keeps failing with the message

```
 TypeError: (0 , _withContext.WithContext) is not a function

      };
export default WithContext(MyComp);
```

Can you please let me know what is wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mocking `withContext` with `jest.doMock` but the mock you are returning from the factory function does not contain a `WithContext` function.

Then when you `require('./MyComp').default` it is using the `withContext` mock within your `MyComp` module and failing when it tries to `export default WithContext(MyComp);` since the `withContext` mock does not define a `WithContext` function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried everything that I can think of. Can you please let me know what can I do to resolve this issue ?  thanks